# What program can convert .mp4 files created in Keynote to .swf files?

Tags: macos, keynote, mp4, adobe-flash

I have created a number of MPEG-4 (.mp4) files from Keynote on my Mac.

I now need to use these on a website, but have been told by the website owners that they require the files in ShockWave Flash (.swf) format.

I'm a novice, so don't have any software at present that can do this

In summary I need a Mac program that can convert these MPEG-4 video files to ShockWave Flash (SWF) files so they can be used on the web.

Comment: What have you tried/researched so far? Please refer to https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2180/how-should-i-ask-about-getting-a-software-recommendation for details on how to ask about software recommendations.

Comment: Everyone is moving flash to html5 - why wouldn't you put the mp4 on the web directly and avoid a potential mp4 -> flash -> html5 conversion chain? even google is ditching flash as outdated, insecure, no longer being developed legacy format. http://www.itpro.co.uk/mobile/24135/google-to-automatically-convert-flash-web-ads-to-html5

Answer (score 1):

There is an app on the App Store called [MovieConverter](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/movieconverter/id413883804?mt=12). They claim to convert mp4 to swf files. Can run in batch mode to convert many at once. sells for $0.99.  Read the reviews and most were good. I haven't used it yet so I can't testify about it. Probably worth a shot for one dollar though.

Comment: I tought it did but not sure. I'll try to find out.

Comment: SWF is a listed conversion type but that all I can vouch too.

Comment: my link took me to an app other than Handbrke. I just caught it this time. I gave another simple app that does list SWF. Thanks for catching my error. I update my answer,